# Активация элемента в дереве

Tags: c++, qt

В `QAbstractItemView` есть сигнал `activated` который генерируется если произошло нажатие на элемент. На этот сигнал у меня подвешен слот  `onItemActivated`:

```
void MyWidget::onItemActivated()
{
    doSmth();
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на элемент я мог проверить какие-то условия(или например вывести диалог для подтверждения пользователем) и в случае необходимости отменить активацию элемента. То есть чтобы `currentIndex` не изменился.

Я пробовал использовать `QItemSelectionModel`:

```
 MyWidget::MyWidget()
 {
  ...
 _ui.treeSignalsView->setModel( _treeModel );
 _ui.treeSignalsView->setSelectionModel( new QItemSelectionModel( _treeModel ) );
 connect( _ui.treeSignalsView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged, this, &MyWidget::onCurrentChanged );
 ...
 }


void MyWidget::onCurrentChanged( const QModelIndex& current, const QModelIndex& previous )
{
    _ui.treeSignalsView->setCurrentIndex(previous);
}
```

Но так сделать не получается, т.к. `setCurrentIndex` опять генерирует `QItemSelectionModel::currentChanged`

Comment: Какой вью используете? QTreeView?

Comment: Да, я использую  QTreeView

Comment: А что происходит в вью при активации элемента? Выделение элемента? Раскрытие ветви? Почему вы хотите стандартное поведение изменять, мб лучше выполнять действия (тот же диалог) по клику на кнопку?

Comment: @gil9red При активации на элемент отображается виджет в котором можно редактировать данные  сопряженные с текущий элементом, и если данные были изменены мне нужно вывести окно подтверждения, и если пользователь не подтвердит, то нужно оставить текущий индекс

Comment: `QAbstractItemView::clearSelection()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать сигнал `selectionChanged`

```
connect( _ui.treeSignalsView->selectionModel(), &QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged, this, &MyWidget::onSelectionChanged );
```

и блокировать повторные сигналы в слоте:

```
void MyWidget::onSelectionChanged( const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected )
{
    if (!deselected.isEmpty() && QMessageBox::question(view, "Question", "Save changes?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No|QMessageBox::Cancel) == QMessageBox::Cancel){
        QSignalBlocker blocker(_ui.treeSignalsView->selectionModel());
        _ui.treeSignalsView->selectionModel()->select(deselected, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect);
    } else {
        doSmth();
    }
}
```